how to add this animation in flutter
i have container when clicked on add button it should render a diffrent container but animation effect should be like this.
i have looked for Tween animation but anything doesn't look like quite what i want. Help is apriciated.
my code has two containers which will changed based on a boolean clickedOnAddPrice, and when clicked on may be later it should switch container, also based on clickedOnAddPrice.

this is my build method code:
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var mQSize = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
    var mQWidth = mQSize.width;
    var mQHeight = mQSize.height;
    if (clickedOnAddPrice) {
      return Container(
        height: 335,
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
            color: Color.fromRGBO(247, 247, 247, 1),
            border: Border.all(color: Color.fromRGBO(238, 240, 243, 1))),
        child: Column(
          children: [
            Row(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
              children: [
                Container(
                  margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 12, top: 8),
                  child: Column(
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                    children: [
                      Text(
                        'Graphic Designing',
                        style: GoogleFonts.poppins(
                            fontSize: 15, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                      ),
                      SizedBox(height: 3),
                      Text(
                        'Logo Designing',
                        style: GoogleFonts.poppins(
                          fontSize: 12,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
                IconButton(
                  onPressed: () {},
                  icon: Icon(Icons.delete_outline_rounded),
                ),
              ],
            ),
            SizedBox(height: 10),
            Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: [
                Text(
                  'Price Details',
                  style: GoogleFonts.poppins(
                      fontSize: 15, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                ),
                SizedBox(width: 10),
                Tooltip(
                  message: 'This is informational data',
                  child: Icon(
                    Icons.info_outline,
                    size: 18,
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),

            // slider
            Column(
              children: [
                SizedBox(height: 10),
                Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
                  children: [
                    Text(
                      '0-1 Yrs',
                      style: GoogleFonts.poppins(
                        fontWeight:
                            workExp == 0 ? FontWeight.bold : FontWeight.normal,
                      ),
                    ),
                    Text(
                      '2-4 Yrs',
                      style: GoogleFonts.poppins(
                        fontWeight: workExp == 0.5
                            ? FontWeight.bold
                            : FontWeight.normal,
                      ),
                    ),
                    Text(
                      '5+ Yrs',
                      style: GoogleFonts.poppins(
                        fontWeight:
                            workExp == 1 ? FontWeight.bold : FontWeight.normal,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
                SizedBox(height: 10),
                Container(
                  margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20),
                  width: double.infinity,
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      color: Colors.white,
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30)),
                  child: CupertinoSlider(
                    activeColor: Colors.blue,
                    divisions: 2,
                    value: workExp,
                    onChanged: (value) {
                      setState(() {
                        workExp = value;
                      });
                    },
                  ),
                ),
                SizedBox(height: 20),
              ],
            ),
            Container(
              margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 12),
              child: Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                children: [
                  SizedBox(
                    width: mQWidth / 2.5,
                    child: TextField(
                      decoration: InputDecoration(
                        fillColor: Colors.white,
                        filled: true,
                        enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                            borderSide: const BorderSide(
                                color: Color.fromRGBO(238, 240, 243, 1)),
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10)),
                        focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                            borderSide: const BorderSide(
                                color: Color.fromRGBO(238, 240, 243, 1)),
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10)),
                        border: OutlineInputBorder(
                            borderSide: const BorderSide(
                                color: Color.fromRGBO(238, 240, 243, 1)),
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10)),
                        labelText: 'Minimum',
                        labelStyle: GoogleFonts.poppins(color: Colors.black),
                        hintStyle: GoogleFonts.poppins(color: Colors.black),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  SizedBox(
                    width: mQWidth / 2.5,
                    child: TextField(
                      decoration: InputDecoration(
                        fillColor: Colors.white,
                        filled: true,
                        enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                            borderSide: const BorderSide(
                                color: Color.fromRGBO(238, 240, 243, 1)),
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10)),
                        focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                            borderSide: const BorderSide(
                                color: Color.fromRGBO(238, 240, 243, 1)),
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10)),
                        border: OutlineInputBorder(
                            borderSide: const BorderSide(
                                color: Color.fromRGBO(238, 240, 243, 1)),
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10)),
                        labelText: 'Maximum',
                        labelStyle: GoogleFonts.poppins(color: Colors.black),
                        hintStyle: GoogleFonts.poppins(color: Colors.black),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
            SizedBox(height: 20),

            Container(
              margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 15),
              child: Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                children: [
                  TextButton(
                    onPressed: () {},
                    child: Text(
                      'May be later',
                      style: GoogleFonts.poppins(
                          color: Colors.red, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                    ),
                  ),
                  ElevatedButton(
                    style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                      shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5)),
                      backgroundColor: Colors.red,
                    ),
                    onPressed: () {
                      //
                    },
                    child: SizedBox(
                      height: 50,
                      width: mQWidth / 3.65,
                      child: Center(
                        child: Text(
                          'Submit',
                          style: GoogleFonts.poppins(
                            color: Colors.white,
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            )
          ],
        ),
      );
    } else {
      return Container(
        height: 60,
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
            color: Color.fromRGBO(247, 247, 247, 1),
            border: Border.all(color: Color.fromRGBO(238, 240, 243, 1))),
        child: Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
          children: [
            Container(
              margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 12, top: 8),
              child: Column(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                children: [
                  Text(
                    'Graphic Designing',
                    style: GoogleFonts.poppins(
                        fontSize: 15, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                  ),
                  SizedBox(height: 3),
                  Text(
                    'Logo Designing',
                    style: GoogleFonts.poppins(
                      fontSize: 12,
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
            Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
              children: [
                TextButton(
                  onPressed: () {
                    setState(() {
                      clickedOnAddPrice = true;
                    });
                  },
                  child: Container(
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadiusDirectional.circular(4),
                      color: Colors.red,
                    ),
                    child: Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                          vertical: 5, horizontal: 12.0),
                      child: Text(
                        'Add Price',
                        style: GoogleFonts.poppins(color: Colors.white),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                IconButton(
                    onPressed: () {}, icon: Icon(Icons.delete_outline_rounded))
              ],
            ),
          ],
        ),
      );
    }
  }
}


Take a look at ExpansionTile

You can refer to my example
A few things to notice:

use 1 Container, because your view has 2 separated child widgets that need to animate simultaneously:  btn add price & details view. You can't use 2 container with if-else, which will cause change the entire view
set _controllerAddPriceBtn with start value = 1.0, so at initial build, the add price btn will be visible
What is the difference between ScaleTransition vs SizeTransition: scale still takes space even child is invisible and has alignment so I  apply it to the btn add price, which scales down toward the center-right


class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> with TickerProviderStateMixin {
  late final _controllerAddPriceBtn = AnimationController(
    duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 500),
    vsync: this,
  )..value = 1.0;
  late final Animation<double> _animationAddPriceBtn = CurvedAnimation(
    parent: _controllerAddPriceBtn,
    curve: Curves.fastOutSlowIn,
  );

  late final _controllerDetailsView = AnimationController(
    duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 500),
    vsync: this,
  );
  late final Animation<double> _animationDetailsView = CurvedAnimation(
    parent: _controllerDetailsView,
    curve: Curves.fastOutSlowIn,
  );

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _controllerAddPriceBtn.dispose();
    _controllerDetailsView.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.inversePrimary,
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
        child: Container(
          decoration: BoxDecoration(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8), color: Colors.black12),
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8),
          child: Column(
            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
            children: [
              SizedBox(
                height: 70,
                child: Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: [
                    const Column(
                      mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                      children: [
                        Text("Graphic designing"),
                        Text("Logo designing"),
                      ],
                    ),
                    const Spacer(),
                    ScaleTransition(
                      alignment: Alignment.centerRight,
                      scale: _animationAddPriceBtn,
                      child: CupertinoButton(
                        child: Container(
                          decoration: BoxDecoration(
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(4),
                            color: Colors.white,
                          ),
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8),
                          child: const Text("Add Price"),
                        ),
                        onPressed: () {
                          _controllerAddPriceBtn.reverse();
                          _controllerDetailsView.forward();
                        },
                      ),
                    ),
                    const SizedBox(width: 10),
                    const Icon(Icons.delete),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
              SizeTransition(
                sizeFactor: _animationDetailsView,
                child: Column(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: [
                    const SizedBox(height: 20),
                    const Row(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                      children: [
                        Text(
                          'Price Details',
                        ),
                        SizedBox(width: 10),
                        Tooltip(
                          message: 'This is informational data',
                          child: Icon(
                            Icons.info_outline,
                            size: 18,
                          ),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                    Row(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                      children: [
                        CupertinoButton(
                          child: const Text("Maybe later"),
                          onPressed: () {
                            _controllerDetailsView.reverse();
                            _controllerAddPriceBtn.forward();
                          },
                        ),
                        CupertinoButton(
                          child: Container(
                            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(4),
                              color: Colors.white,
                            ),
                            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8),
                            child: const Text("Submit"),
                          ),
                          onPressed: () {},
                        ),
                      ],
                    )
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}


thanks! sir, i am new to animations could you explain your code, what are methods and how to use them.

hi, added some explanations to the answer.
